# Django, m2m count annotation related model with condition

Tags: django, count, annotations, django-queryset, m2m

so my models:

```
class User(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_lenght=255)

class Group(models.Model):
    users = models.ManyToManyField('User')

class ActiveGroup(models.Model):
    group = models.ForeignKey('Group', null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    user = models.OneToOneField('User')
```

So the deal is every user can be a member of any group ( which is represented by m2m field on Group model). But can be active member in only one of them at the same time ( thats why oneToOneField relation on activegroup model).

Problem: need to make a queryset for Group models with count of users which are active.
so its suppose to be like

```
SELECT group.id, COUNT(
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM activegroup WHERE activegroup.group_id = group.group.id
) as users_count FROM group.
```

I've tried django.db.models Case and When things but nothing helps.

Comment: I assume you delete from the database the relation ActiveGroup from a user in case it is not active in a specific group anymore?

Comment: not at all, i just set user.acivegroup.group = None

Comment: but usuall active group just changed to another.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you changing your database design. You have rows with partially-empty entries AND duplication. And that's not good. If this project is expected to grow, you might face problems in the future.

For example: `Group -> User` and `ActiveGroup.group -> user`. It is the same information stored two times. I'd change it before going to production. My suggestion would be using through:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships

You could create a boolean field called "active" and simply switch that every time the active group is changed.

But of course, these are only suggestions. :)

Your solution is:

```
Group.objects.annotate(total=Count('activegroup__user'))

ag = Group.objects.annotate(total=Count('activegroup__user'))
for g in ag:
    print(g, g.total)

>> group_1 2
   group_2 1
```

In your model, you might face another group called `null`, which will be users without group.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#annotate

Comment: ty very much, for your suggestions and solution

Comment: your way Group.objects.annotate(total=Count('activegroup__user')) i solved through extra qs for now and ```  query = 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "{activegroup}" WHERE "{activegroup}"."group_id" = "{group}"."id"'  # NOQA
        format_kwargs = {
            'activegroup': ActiveGroup._meta.db_table,
            'group': self.model._meta.db_table
        }
        return self.extra(select={
            'users_count': query.format(**format_kwargs)})``` but your way is much better

Comment: That's true. You can use aggregate in `ActiveGroup` instead and count the users. :)

Comment: If it worked, don't forget to mark as the correct answer for your question. ;)